# Rendering Shiny Selectize pull-down menu on top

Tags: r, shiny

This is a simplification of my Shiny UI. My issue is that the pull-down menu from the SelectizeInput is hidden. It is a bit of a pain having to scroll down. Also, it just does not look very nice. I have tried playing with the z-index to bring it up front but have not had any success.

This is my code:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
                tabPanel("Search",
                         fluidRow(
                           column(12,
                                  inputPanel(
                                    selectizeInput("s1", h4("Select State:"),
                                                   choices = state.name),
                                    tags$head(tags$style(".selectize-control.single { width: 400px; z-index: 1; }")),
                                    dateInput("day", h4("Input Date:"), value = Sys.Date())
                                  )
                           )
                         )
                )
    )),
  server = function(input,output,session) 
    {

  })
)
```

Basically, I want the SelectizeInput menu to display on top like the DateInput calendar.

Thanks for the help!

Carlos

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the options from the `selectize.js` library https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md . `dropdownParent`maybe what you are looking for:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
                tabPanel("Search",
                         fluidRow(
                           column(12,
                                  inputPanel(
                                    selectizeInput("s1", h4("Select State:")
                                                   , options = list(dropdownParent = 'body')
                                                   , choices = state.name),
                                    tags$head(tags$style(".selectize-control.single { width: 400px; z-index: 1; }")),
                                    dateInput("day", h4("Input Date:"), value = Sys.Date())
                                  )
                           )
                         )
                )
    )),
  server = function(input,output,session) 
  {

  })
)
```

[image]

Alternatively you can look at CSS and something like the `overflow` attribute. See [Dropdowns not extending in shiny tabPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233841/dropdowns-not-extending-in-shiny-tabpanel/23234577#23234577) . So in this case use

```
tags$head(tags$style(".tab-content {overflow: visible;}")),
```

Comment: +1 FWIW, the overflow approach does seem to work. The CSS doesn't take effect.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde yeah the overflow will work but maybe better to use the built-in selectize option to have the menu a child of the `body`

Comment: Oh, I see. I tried applying the style to the wellpanel and the select input, but not the tab panel. Thanks.